# MongoDB find Query with date comparison ( NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and I've been trying to get scheduled control messages in my collection , for example one CM is scheduled for today 15h and now is 15h, by logic i should compare the date using `$lte` (less than or equal)

**the query:**

```
/*Getting the Date (my schedule is only with hours and minutes)*/

var nowDate = new Date();
nowDate.setSeconds(0);
nowDate.setMilliseconds(0);


/*The Query*/ 
dbo.collection("control_message").find(
            { "status": { $in: [3,4] }},
            {
                $or: [ { schedule:{$exists: false}},{schedule:{date:{ $lte :nowDate}}}]
            }

        )
```

**why i am asking this?**

because there are  CMs (control messages) scheduled for 17h even though now it's 15h and the query is getting them.

I printed the `nowDate` to verify: `2020-12-13T15:33:00.000Z`

The scheduled time is: `2020-12-13T17:00:00.000Z`

**same query on MySQL (works):**

```
SELECT id_control_message AS control_message_id , app_id, title, body, channel,url_push, img_push, silent, status 
                            FROM control_message 
                            WHERE (status = 3 OR status = 4) 
                            AND (schedule IS NULL OR schedule <= NOW())
```

**Control Message Document example:**

```
{
_id: '5fd3e48eac3f2b3ede0a6a52',
sent_in: {
  date: 2020-12-11T21:28:46.760Z,
  short_date: 2020-12-11T21:28:46.760Z
},
sender_id: 266,
app_id: 190,
message_type_id: 1,
title: '',
body: '',
schedule: {
  date: 2020-12-13T17:00:00.000Z,
  short_date: 2020-12-13T17:00:00.000Z
},
ip: '172.31.55.83',
status: 4
}
```

Comment: are you sure because `2020-12-13T17:00:00.000Z` is not less than `2020-12-13T15:33:00.000Z` so this document will not return in result, look at the [playgorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kcM0iLmzN62)

Comment: @turivishal Thank you man, paying attention to the small details of the playground example , i corrected my query and it's working now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal), I've noticed in the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kcM0iLmzN62) example he sent me that the logic of the my query was wrong since i didn't add the `$and` operator,it wasn't returning the right results.
Not only that , but specifying which date to compare with `"schedule.date"` instead of using just `"schedule"`  was the correct way to compare (in my case)

**The corrected query:**

```
dbo.collection("control_message").find({
        $and: [
            {"status": { $in: [3,4] }},
            {
                $or: [ { schedule:{$exists: false}},{"schedule.date":{ $lte :nowDate}}]
            }

         ]
          })
```